# Refresh the content within Google Maps iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am currently working with the Google Maps API for iOS. I have drawn markers on the maps, but I do not know how to "refresh" (delete markers and redraw new ones) the markers once the user has entered in new data from another class. I try to recall the map view class like this:

This is the code, in another class (GetInfoViewController) that is executed when the user inputs new data

```
MapViewController *mapVC = [[MapViewController alloc]init];
[mapVC resetMap];
```

This is what is inside the MapViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    getpos = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

- (void)loadView {

    lat = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    lng = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    markers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m


    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition   cameraWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                                            longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude                                                                 zoom:13.2];

    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView.delegate = self;

    self.view = mapView;
    [mapView clear];
    [self createMarker];

}


- (void) createMarker {

    [lat removeAllObjects];
    [lng removeAllObjects];
    [markers removeAllObjects];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    for (int x = 0; x < [appDelegate.geocodedLatArrayGlobal count]; x++) {
        NSNumber *latCoord = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[appDelegate.geocodedLatArrayGlobal objectAtIndex:x]doubleValue]];
        [lat addObject: latCoord];
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < [appDelegate.geocodedLngArrayGlobal count]; x++) {
        NSNumber *lngCoord = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[appDelegate.geocodedLngArrayGlobal objectAtIndex:x]doubleValue]];
        [lng addObject:lngCoord];
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < [lat count]; x++) {
        double latitude =[[lat objectAtIndex:x]doubleValue];
        double longitude =[[lng objectAtIndex:x]doubleValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude) ;
        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
        marker.title = @"Title"
        marker.map = mapView;
        [markers addObject:marker];

    }

}

-(void)resetMap{
       NSLog(@"map reset");
       [mapView clear];
       [self createMarker];
}
```

In GetInfoViewController: Changing the container content to MapViewController

```
 MapViewController *viewController1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc1"];
    viewController1.view.frame = self.container.bounds;

    [viewController1 willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.container addSubview:viewController1.view];
    [self addChildViewController:viewController1];
    [viewController1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight  forView:self.container cache:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Don't call viewDidLoad manually.

Comment: would i call loadView then? I have already tried to call both loadView and createMarkers, and nothing updates on the map

Comment: When the user updates something call mapView clear and then load all your markers again. This is not the best way but we can try to find whats not working.

Comment: If you mean calling it in the MapViewController class, in loadView i call  [mapView clear]; and nothing happens to the marker. The code MapViewController *mapVC = [[MapViewController alloc]init];
[mapVC viewDidLoad]; is called in a separate class if you are wondering

Comment: Ok where does this "user has entered in new data" happen??

Comment: user input happeneds in the class GetInfoViewController. The code of MapViewController *mapVC = [[MapViewController alloc]init];
[mapVC viewDidLoad]; is called when a button is pressed

Comment: What changes does the user make that would appear in the mapview, does he select a set of points to be shown. Where do you do that in createMarkers function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34417/discussion-between-alexyuiop-and-satheeshwaran)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: I was allocating and initializing a whole new MapViewController each time the button was pressed

```
MapViewController *mapVC = [[MapViewController alloc]init];
[mapVC resetMap];
```

So i created a global variable, only allocated and initialized once in viewDidLoad, to use in my code

Answer (score 2):

To clear markers on Google Maps for ios use the [clear](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view#a28e6b8aeb7c8dc9025dc001f2a5d2c9b) function of your GMSMapView instance. Although I suggest you recycle existing markers by changing its properties like its position.

Comment: I do [mapView clear]; in the loadView method, and nothing gets cleared/updated

Comment: There is nothing to be cleared when you call the [mapView clear] since there are no markers yet on your mapview. Remember that loadView will be called only once. You can put the clear markers on a separate function and call it as needed. And also don't call viewDidload manually.

Comment: ok I created a separate method to clear the map and place new markers, but still, the map is not being cleared and new markers are not showing up. (code above has been updated)

Comment: Just a question, how do you display the MapViewController? Do you push it in the navigation stack like calling [[self.navigationController]pushViewController:mapView animated:YES]; in your GetInfoViewController? Did you check if the data you're getting from AppDelegate changes?

Comment: the MapViewController is displayed when the user taps a button to change a container view's content from a table view to this mapview (edited code above to show the code for showing MapViewController)